why is bazel passing $(version) instead of the value of Version?
I am trying to pass a Version to my BUILD.bazel file so i can overwrite the variable in my main so i could print it but its not working.
go_binary(
    name = "api",
    embed = [":api_lib"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    x_defs = {"main.Version": "$(Version)"},

)

and in my make file i do this
@bazelisk build  --define Version=1.9 //...


when i run my app it prints $(Version) in the Version instead of 1.9

It doesn't look like x_defs does make variable substitution, it's not mentioned in the docs:
https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/blob/master/docs/go/core/rules.md#go_binary-x_defs
That's something that the go rules would need to add support for.
Following those docs, it appears x_defs will work with build stamping though:
https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/blob/master/docs/go/core/defines_and_stamping.md#defines-and-stamping
So you could try something like x_defs = {"main.Version": "{STABLE_Version}"}, with --workspace_status_command="echo STABLE_Version 0.9"

The thing is:  if its not printing  $(Version) it would be empty, meaning it's not setting the variable in the main.go with what i entered

Right, because the x_defs attribute in the go rules doesn't support the $(variable) syntax. The docs say it supports {variable} syntax with build stamping though. Did you try the suggestion above?

I tried every possible way to pass the variable using --define and stamping even with workspace_status_command

And for {version}  i have originally written it that way but on the main.go where i print the version, it stays empty
